# Why it is possible to print "correctly" an Integer object in java?

Tags: java

```
Integer ki=new Integer("50");
System.out.println(ki);//Here I would expect to print the objects name something like package_name.Class@15db9742 but this didn't happen.
ki=3;//Here I would expect an error but this actually works.
```

When **System.out.println(ki);** executed then 50 appeared in the console but when I print other objects some thing like package_name.Class@15db9742 appears why 50 appeared instead of something like package_name.Class@15db9742?

I though ki is type Integer so when I assign the primitive value of 3 I should get an error but I didn't why?

Comment: learn about boxing and autoboxing: http://beginnersbook.com/2014/09/java-autoboxing-and-unboxing-with-examples/

Comment: You should go through Java tutorials to at least get acquainted with the basic language semantics.

Comment: @AndrewLi unfortunatelly the answer in that post wasn't really helpfull.

Comment: @xlxs Are you sure? It explains the 'weird printing' quite well. Your second question is answered by reading the Javadocs on autoboxing and autounboxing

Comment: @AndrewLi oups sorry my wrong it is helpful

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have two separate questions there:

> ```
> System.out.println(ki);//Here I would expect to print the objects name something like package_name.Class@15db9742 but this didn't happen.
> ```

Because [`Integer` overrides `toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString--). Its implementation:

```
public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(value);
}
```

<s>Hmm...or because [`println(int)` exists on `PrintStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-int-).</s>

Nope, it's calling `System.out.println(Object)`, which then uses `toString` on the object. This is because (as the [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2) tells us) the rule is to first try to find a matching signature without auto-(un)boxing and without varargs; then just with auto-(un)boxing, then at last with both.

> ```
>  ki=3;//Here I would expect an error but this actually works.
> ```

That's because of [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7): The Java compiler inserts the necessary code to take that primitive `3` and create an `Integer` instance for it. The bytecode it actually emits does this:

```
ki = Integer.valueOf(3);
```

Comment: If im correct Integer is a final class. Can methods of final classes get overriden ?

Comment: @xlxs: You're correct that it's `final`, and no, the point of a final class is that it cannot be subclassed; since only subclasses can override methods, a final class's methods cannot be overridden. `Integer` overrides `Object`'s `toString` (`Number` is in-between them, but doesn't override `toString`), but `Integer`'s `toString` can't be overridden because it cannot be subclassed.

Comment: Thank's for the help :)